# are Runtime Revolution (RunRev) aka LiveCode based apps now accepted in iPhone marketplace?

Tags: iphone, ios, marketplace, livecode

on their website they have "announcements" made at various times saying that it is either prohibited or allowed. The latest announcement, as of September 2010, seems to say that it is allowed, but then maybe there are some more that I haven't located prohibiting it.

So what is the final truth of the matter now? Does Apple marketplace accept RunRev stuff or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest announcement is correct, and Apple is permitting apps built with [Livecode/Rev/whatever we're calling it this year] in the iOS App Store. The first one, I think, was [Sheep Herder](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/artist/runrev-ltd/id399057639), but there are others.

Apple had initially said this was OK, then changed its mind during the Great Steve Versus Flash Incident of 2010. (Rev was collateral damage, along with all other non-Apple development platforms). Then it changed its mind back. So the situation changed several times before it stabilized, which is why the Rev blog and forum archives have different announcements at different times.

Comment: There was an issue with LiveCode using private API's. Consequently, only apps built with LC 5.5.5 and 6.0.2 or later will be accepted by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

As a further development, LiveCode iOS apps built with the forthcoming open source licensed LiveCode will not be allowed in the App Store because of licensing issues. Apps developed with the commercial license (paid) LiveCode will still be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are very many more than just Sheep Herder in the app store - I ran a survey a bit over a year ago (November 2011) and some 40 people sent me appstore links to their apps.

You can see a bunch of stuff-built-with Livecode, including a number of apps, here:

http://livecode1001.blogspot.co.uk/